# REST API parameters validation in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, validation, rest

I am writing a Rails application that has a REST API only (no web interface or such). I need to check if the requests are being made with the right parameters and return different error codes if not. For example, all my API endpoints require a user_access_token, and a client_id. Some other endpoints require other different parameters to be present.

In all the controllers, I have the code that does this checking, but the code is getting duplicated, and there are many if-conditions that can be extracted out and put somewhere else. So I thought of adding a `before_filter` in my `ApplicationController` that does this checking. I defined a hash that contains all the endpoint to required_params mapping, and this filter runs before the control passes to the actual controller in question.

But for some endpoints, it is getting a little complicated because some parameters are required if some other parameters are present, and in some cases one of two parameters is required. So now I am wondering if there is a better way of doing this.

Am I doing it right? Is there a better/standardized way of doing this? Or some gem that does this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would have to see some code to understand the context. But it essentiallys sounds like you have your base ApplicationController that all of your other controller's inherit from. The thing that varies is the parameters that you expect (except for user_access_token and client_id which always need to be supplied). Since you are using inheritance you could define a method in your ApplicationController that contains a list of which parameters you expect and then in your subclasses override the method to check add other params. Your base controller will be responsible for doing the actual validation but the subclasses will get a chance to override the required parameters.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :validate_params

  protected

  def required_params
    [:user_access_token, :client_id]
  end

  def validate_params
    unless (require_params - params.keys).count.zero?
      # do something
    end
  end
end

class AnotherController < ApplicationController
  protected

  def required_params
    p = super + [:email, :password]
    p = p + [:another, :and_another] if some_condition?
    p
  end
end
```

Essentially you would let the subclass decide if it needed to add any additional required parameters. Of course I don't know what your exact context is, but hopefully this will help you in the right direction. Do some research on polymorphism when you get the chance :-)

Comment: Oh my god! This is another one of my Ruby-is-awesome moments! Coming from years of Java experience, I was checking `params[:name].nil?` for each param, and that was making it hard. This should help me! Thanks a lot.